# Dynamic searchParameters in http request of jmeter

Tags: csv, testing, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

[image: This is my ThreadGroup]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

IndexFile.csv is like

```js
type,text,code,,,FileOne.csv
req,,,,,FileTwo.csv
And soo on which means dynamic number of params for http request
```

FileOne.csv is like

```js
44-3ef-k23,string,http://someThing:port/Something|something
string,"string,string",1234
```

So i need http encoding i.e utf-8 while reading file.

Can someone help me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

One thing is obvious: you should not be using [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) inside the JSR223 script.

According to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> JMeter processes function and variable references before passing the script field to the interpreter, so the references will only be resolved once. Variable and function references in script files will be passed verbatim to the interpreter, which is likely to cause a syntax error. In order to use runtime variables, please use the appropriate props methods, e.g.
>
> ```
> props.get("START.HMS");
> props.put("PROP1","1234");
> ```

So I would suggest to use [File.readLines()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#readLines()) function in order to read your CSV file(s) into memory, once done you should be able to call [split()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#split()) function to split each line by comma and do what you need with the results.

Check out **Working with Files** chapter of [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) article for more information and examples

Comment: But here the problem is the data is huge in the file and the buffer will run out of memory, so is it possible in any way to read a single line per iteration of the loop. And can you write down the split function with separator as semicolan (;) and http encoding for the values